# The right way to load a PDF into an ImageView

Tags: java, android, pdf

I'm looking for the proper way to load a PDF File into an ImageView.
I use the BitmapWorkerTask class from Android.
I have a button which allow me to choose the File I want to upload into the ImageView. When I click on this file, the process begin.
My issue is that my PDF is perfectly load 3 time 5. And I don't understand why it's not working the other time.

```
ImageView map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    map = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.pdf);
}

/**
 * Use this to load a pdf file from your assets and render it to a Bitmap.
 * 
 * @param context
 *            current context.
 * @param filePath
 *            of the pdf file in the assets.
 * @return a bitmap.
 */
@Nullable
public static Bitmap renderToBitmap(Context context, String filePath) {
    Bitmap bi = null;
    InputStream  inStream = null;
    try {
        inStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        bi = renderToBitmap(context, inStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            inStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // do nothing because the stream has already been closed
        }
    }
    return bi;
}

/**
 * Use this to render a pdf file given as InputStream to a Bitmap.
 * 
 * @param context
 *            current context.
 * @param inStream
 *            the inputStream of the pdf file.
 * @return a bitmap.
 * @see https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library/
 */
@Nullable
public static Bitmap renderToBitmap(Context context, InputStream inStream) {
    Bitmap bi = null;
    try {
        byte[] decode = IOUtils.toByteArray(inStream);
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(decode);
        PDFPage mPdfPage = new PDFFile(buf).getPage(0);
        float width = mPdfPage.getWidth();
        float height = mPdfPage.getHeight();
        RectF clip = null;
        bi = mPdfPage.getImage((int) (width), (int) (height), clip, true,
                true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            inStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // do nothing because the stream has already been closed
        }
    }
    return bi;
}

private void renderMap() {

    String mapFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Android/data/com.empower.data/"+mapFileName;

    BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(map, mapFilePath, MainActivity.this);
    task.loadBitmap(R.id.pdf, map, mapFilePath);
    map.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    map.invalidate();
}
```

And my BitmapWorkerTask.java

```
public class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
 private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
 private int data = 0;
 private String mapFilePath1;
 private Context context;
 private RelativeLayout loadingPanel;

 public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView, String mapFilePath2, Context context) {
     // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
    this.context = context;
    mapFilePath1 = mapFilePath2;
     imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
 }

 // Decode image in background.
 @Override
 protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
     data = params[0];

     Bitmap bm = MainActivity.renderToBitmap(context , mapFilePath1);
     return bm;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPreExecute() {
     loadingPanel = (RelativeLayout)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.loadingPanel);
     loadingPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 }

 // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(final Bitmap bitmap) {
     if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
         final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
         if (imageView != null) {
             new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                     loadingPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                 }
               }, 500);
         }
     }
 }

 public void loadBitmap(int resId, ImageView imageView, String mapFilePath1) {

    BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView, mapFilePath1, context);
    task.execute(resId);
 }


 }
```

Comment: what is happening when its not working. is there any error

Comment: For instance, the first time I load it, I have only 1/4 of the image, the second time half of it. And finally, after 3 loads the image is perfectly load in.

Comment: seems like issue with inputstream or buffer, isn't there any callback provided by the library when it is successful or not

Comment: Unfortunately, even when I look at the logcat I can't see anything related to this part of code. It provides no error/warning.

Comment: because this piece of code isn't posting anything to logcat!simple

Comment: You should probably remove the loadBitmap method and call task.execute directly in the renderMap method. Now you are creating 2 instances of BitmapWorker which may be causing problems.